# Android forever in background

Tags: android

I would like to write an application for my Android. This app should write to file every change on my battery like percentage, voltage, remaining RAM, current date and time, etc. But also I would like to get this app in background and when I switch out from my app, sometimes OS kill my application. That is THE issue. Somewhere I have read about possibility to do it with BroadcastReciever and I have one set to react on battery change, but It doesn't solves the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably because you've shown little research effort, and the solution you did find, you shoot down without saying why it doesn't fit your needs.

Comment: not true, to explain my situation, it is about school project and I am not native english speaker, besides I am running out of time and my finals are just around the corner, I have tried using startForeground(id, notification) but it spits some kind of error all the time, so I have asked for help here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use foreground service, OS will not kill it, see [Running a Service in the Foreground](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground)